# AppExchange to generate PDF of a record

Tags: pdf, appexchange, app

I need a free app to generate PDF of a order with the order items in a table, I need to choose the fields that will be displayed, also I need a header and the logo needs to be changed to another one based on a field.

I need ASAP and I'm trying to download every app to see if I can find, so it would be a huge help

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you can likely do this without an app by creating a custom Visualforce page using  `renderAs="pdf"`.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_renderas.htm